# How to take the last one element or request again if error (RxJava + Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Have an implementation of the API endpoints via Retrofit which returns `Observable`.

```
Observable<Post> postObservable = sampleApi.getPost(1);
```

Need something to similar `cache` operator of rx, but without caching of errors.

So if the first subscriber of `postObservable` gets an error, the second subscriber after that can get Post object in`onNext` consumer, after `postObservable` request API again.
So if the first subscriber of `postObservable` gets a Post object in`onNext` consumer, the second subscriber after that gets same Post object in `onNext` consumer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, but can't sure it's correct and not so elegant:

```
    postObservable = Observable.wrap(
            new ObservableSource<Post>() {
                private Post lastResult;

                @Override
                public void subscribe(Observer<? super Post> observer) {
                    if (lastResult == null) {
                        sampleApi.getPost(1)
                                .doOnNext(post -> lastResult = post)
                                .subscribe(observer);
                    } else {
                        Observable.just(lastResult)
                                .subscribe(observer);
                    }
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```